# Postres SQL select with GROUP BY and COUNT

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, count, aggregate-functions

i have this SQL select

```
SELECT t.debtor_account, COUNT(t.debtor_account)
FROM transaction t
GROUP BY t.debtor_account
HAVING COUNT(t.debtor_account) > 2;
```

which work, but i need select all from transaction.
But when i try SELECT * FROM ...... i get this error:
**column "t.account_fk" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function**
Any idea for select with same functionality, but with select all instead of just debtor_account ? Thanks...

Btw. Table scheme [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytPPj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t.debtor_account) as cnt
      FROM transaction t
     ) t
WHERE cnt > 2
ORDER BY debtor_account;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want window functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY debtor_account) cnt
    FROM transaction t
) t
WHERE cnt > 2
```